# Custom XPath in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, xpath

I'm wondering if anyone out there as built a custom script or stored procedure that will accept a field and an XPath expression to return.  Even if it's really clumsy, I'll take it.

Something like this:

```
FindByXPath(fieldName, query);
```

Which I would give values:

```
FindByXPath([xmlContent], '/root/customer/country[@attribute]');
```

All I need is basic node and attribute selection.  I'm using MySQL 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrade to MySQL 5.1.  It supports [ExtractValue(xml_frag, xpath_expr)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/xml-functions.html#function_extractvalue)

Comment: I thought I was using 5.1.  Guess not